# Get user id from session - laravel 5.3 authentication

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I have fresh Laravel 5.3 installation. Just used the `php artisan make:auth`
 to get started with built in auth functionalities. All works fine, and after login the `Auth::check()` returns true, `Auth::user()` return the user's data and `Auth::id()` gives the logged in user's id.

What bothering me is that when I have only this line

```
$userId = Auth:id();
```

in my controller's action (and no other code elsewhere associated with Auth) in the Debugger panel's "Queries" tab I see the following query

```
select * from `users` where `users`.`id` = '34' limit 1
```

This extra query is highly undesirable to me (especially the select all part), as I need the user's id to make a query, selecting specific fields from users table, as well as to join it with another tables. For performance reasons I do not want to do double query.

So, is there a way to tell Laravel to save the logged in user's id in session(if it is not being saved) and get the **id** of the logged in user directly from session - without making any query to the database.

**EDIT:** I understand that after first `Auth::user()` call, the subsequent calls will not make requests to the database, however it is pointless, why make `select *` query, if I will need only some columns from the database. At least is there a way to tell Laravel to select only specific columns, instead of `select *` ?

Thanks

Comment: To give your application a roundabout way to get the user id just because a `select *` is not optimized strikes me as a fallacy. You will have a negligible gain in performance and memory use, but eventually lose big in having a non-standard Laravel app. The whole idea behind a framework is ease-of-development vs. micro-managing / micro-optimization. If you want this level of customization, I would advise you not to use Laravel.

Comment: @TomasButeler, thanks for the advice, but have to disagree that being against `select *` is a micro-optimization. I think the ease of development of the framework should not interfere with the performance on such simple tasks as this, and as popular framework as laravel should have had this option IMHO

Comment: I'm sorry but I do not agree with what Tomas Buteler is saying. Laravel was designed to spin up applications quickly but it comes with it's quirks when it comes to customization. Yet, frameworks as robust as Laravel are supposed to be dynamic enough to allow you the ability to customize and for the framework to be smart enough to work the way you need it to....mostly. 
The project I'm working on we use Laravel 100% on the server-side and our project requires laravel to be customized to some degree. 
Where else are you calling Auth() Facade? or making a reference to auth??

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to execute another query. Use this object to get other properties:

```
auth()->user()->name
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but it does not work, meaning - it again makes the `select *` query. I do not want to `select *`, get all the columns and use only some, pure optimization, is not it ?

Comment: Laravel always executes one query for logged in user. It will not execute another query if you'll use the object. If you want to turn it off for most of requests, I'm afraid you'll need to use your own or 3rd party auth system. But it doesn't make any sense since Laravel reads session from file or DB too.

Comment: I understand that pretty well, the problem is, lets say I only need the user's first_name, last_name and email, why laravel does `select *`, it is useless to make `select *` query if the other columns will not be used

Comment: Laravel does this because it's common case. You can keep all other columns in another model/table (i.e. `Profile`) and create one-to-one relationship between this model and `User`

Comment: thanks, I am aware of the workarounds, but that is not a good option. Just decided to give laravel a try and already a bad start ((. thanks anyway :)

Comment: Well people love Laravel because these things work out of box and are suitable for most apps. It's sad to hear you don't like it.

Comment: Well, not gonna quit at once )) but anyway, do not like unoptimized queries... how can someone like `select *` if one does not need all the columns